# Do vuex modules still require namespacing?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have set up a rather large Vuex project with multiple modules.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

To grab the example of a getter a getter from a `search` module could be addressed like so:

```
computed: {
    filters() {
        return this.$store.state.search.filters;
    }
}
```

Because I need to access the state of the module by referencing the `search` property in my property chain do I still need to namespace my module?

The documentation states the following:

> By default, actions, mutations and getters inside modules are still
>   registered under the global namespace - this allows multiple modules
>   to react to the same mutation/action type.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#namespacing

But if the module is under its own property in the store isn't the only conflict that could happen between modules themselves, which can easily be prevented by a simple naming convention of the files?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But if the module is under its own property in the store isn't the only conflict that could happen between modules themselves, which can easily be prevented by a simple naming convention of the files?

No, you misunderstand. The state itself is properly namespaced, but mutations, actions and getters are still collected on a global level so you can e.g. dispatch one Action and several actions from different modules react to it.

That's the default behavior, but the good news is, that there's an option to namespace mutations, actions and getters: "namespaced: true".

it's documented here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#

Scroll down to the "Namespacing" section.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this made it pretty clear.